# how to use any character match followed by an optional matching pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have this input, name &cp_name (,10)

My requirements are ,

- starting shouldnt be a space
- 'name' should be matched by any chracter(.+) as it can be anything
- '&cp_name' (optional)
- '()' a bracket anything can be inside it (optional)

Note: All these three can be separated with one or more spaces

```
    (?P<field>[^\s].+?)\s*(?P<col>[&][a-zA-Z_]+)?\s*(?P<pos>\(.*?\))?
```

The Regex i tried in python
I expect one match with 3 captured groups

- field -> name
- col -> &cp_name
- pos -> (,10)

what i get , 2 matches

1st match :

- field -> 'na'

2nd match:

- field -> 'me '
- col -> '&cp_name'
- pos -> '(,10)'

Comment: How should be parsed `'name (x)'`, field='name' and pos='(x)' or field='name (x)' pos=''?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the field group you can start by matching not a whitespace char and then match any non whitespace chars.

Since the field group can contain spaces you can repeat that and make sure that the words do not start with `&` or with opening and closing parenthesis.

```
^(?P<field>(?![^\s&]*&)\S+(?: (?!\([^)]*\)|[^&\s]*&)\S+)*)\s*(?P<col>&[a-zA-Z_]+)?\s*(?P<pos>\(.*?\))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<field>` Named group field

  - `(?![^\s&]*&)\S+` Assert what is on the right does not contain a `&`, then match 1+ times a non whitespace char
  - `[^\s&]\S+` match not a whitespace char or `&` followed by matching 1+ times a non whitespace char
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\([^)]*\))\S+` Assert what is on the right is not `(`...`)`, then  match 1+ times a non whitespace char
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group field
- `\s*(?P<col>&[a-zA-Z_]+)?` Match optional `col` group
- `\s*(?P<pos>\(.*?\))?` Match optional `pos` group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q3aFp0/1)

Note that you can omit the square brackets around `[&]`

Comment: Yes. I thought of that. But the problem is the field value can have space.
for example :  print_name(name, 10)

Comment: @ArunKumar If the fieldname can not have `()&` then you could try https://regex101.com/r/6bInMf/2

Comment: You could also repeat not matching the ampersand in a non greedy way https://regex101.com/r/6bInMf/3

Comment: The field name can have `()` but not `&`

Comment: Thanks ! That really helped me out